# SSRS 2012 Report Builder does not execute report with subreports

Tags: reporting-services-2012

I have SSRS 2012 report with subreports linked to with parameters from tablix' TextBoxes in main report.
All reports have shared data source.
Problem: I cannot start main report in Report Builder.
I was able to run subreports by setting default parameters.  But main report's  load icon is just sitting frozen after clicking. I changed Windows authentication to SQL Server, this did not any.
In both kind of authentication I use SQL Server sysadmin logins.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Report Builder is only working for a single report. So when you execute a report which contains a subreport, the subreport can't be processed.